# What does this Experience Profile error mean?

Tags: xdb

I have a Sitecore 9.1.1 distributed instance. I am seeing this in the CMS site log files a lot. Not sure at all what it means.

```
10360 15:50:06 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP POST
URL https://mycmserver.com/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/search?&pageSize=20&pageNumber=1&sort=visitCount desc&Match=*&FromDate=null&ToDate=null

Exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.Plumbing.NegotiateLanguageFilter.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Is your Solr service running and available by url from connection strings?

Comment: what is Sitecore version?

Comment: The Sitecore version is 9.1.1

Comment: Yes Solr is running and available by URL from the connection string.

Comment: Is xConnect running? This looks like an API call is being made they errors out on a call to xConnect for search.

Answer (score 1):

I opened a Sitecore Support ticket and found out that the reason for this error was because my CM server was missing a connection string to xconnect.search.  Once I added that in then this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

The `NegotiateLanguageFilter` appears to be an MVC action filter that appends the current Sitecore Context Language into the Content Headers of the response.  The effect of this is that whatever code is processing the response will "know" the language/culture of the response body.

The actual code in the method mentioned looks like this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    if (actionExecutedContext != null)
    {
        actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Language", Context.Language.Name);
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's unremarkable.

The candidates for a NRE are probably:

- `actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers` == `null`  (I doubt this is possible)
- `Context.Language` == `null` (again, I feel like this is only barely possible)
- `Context.Language.Name` == `null` (and therefore the act of adding the header is the thing that's failing)

My money is on the last one - go check the configured languages in Control Panel and delete any you don't need.  Also check the database to see if there are language codes that are in there that have become orphaned from the language in Sitecore.  If there are you need to add the language to Sitecore, then remove it again.

Use Control Panel, not just the System tree as the Control Panel way will clean up all the content for you when you delete the Language, where the tree will not.